# Python tkinter label background image

Tags: python, tkinter, background

I want to put a background image on a label, but with the text still displaying.

```
img = tk.Photoimage(file = "image.png")
tk.Label(root, text = "test", image = img).pack()
```

But the text doesn't display. I think it's covered by the image.

Comment: Read it https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btkinter%5D+label+background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `compound` option of `Label` to tell how to put the text and image together:

```
tk.Label(root, text='test', image=img, compound='center')
```

will put the text at the center of image.

Other options:

```
'left', 'top', 'right', 'bottom': put the image at the specified side of text.
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You just saved me an hour of coding.